# В чем разница между методами map и flatMap в Java 8?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-8, java-stream, java-faq

Чем отличаются методы [`Stream.map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) и [`Stream.flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) друг от друга?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8

Answer (score 22, accepted):

И `map` и `flatMap` могут быть применены к стриму `Stream<T>` и оба возвращают стрим `Stream<R>`. Разница заключается в том, что операция `map` создает одно выходное значение для каждого входного значения, тогда как операция `flatMap` создает произвольное число(ноль или больше) значений для каждого входного значения.

---

Операция `map`([О работе `map` на русском](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-8-stream-map/)) в качестве аргумента принимает `Function`(например, лямбду), которая вызывается для каждого значения входного стрима(который `<T>`), преобразует это значение в другое значение, и посылает получившееся значение в выходной стрим(который `<R>`).

Т.е. `map` для каждого объекта в стриме возвращает по 1 объекту, потом преобразует все объекты в итоговый стрим.

---

Операция `flatMap`([О работе `flatMap` на русском](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-8-stream-flatmap/)) принимает функцию (которая преобразует каждое значение входного стрима в стрим), применяет ее к каждому элементу, и на выходе возвращает стрим с одним, несколькими или ни c одним из элементов **для каждого элемента** входящего стрима.

Т.е., `flatMap` возвращает по стриму для каждого объекта в первоначальном стриме, а затем результирующие потоки объединяются в исходный стрим.

---

Пример для `map`: есть одномерный массив `array` с числами. Нужно получить массив из первоначального массива, в котором к каждому числу прибавлена 1.

Решение:

```
array = Arrays.stream(array) //преобразовываем массив в стрим
              .map(i -> i+1) //преобразовываем каждый элемент стрима
              .toArray();    //преобразовываем стрим в массив
```

`map` к каждому значению стрима прибавляет 1, потом все новые значения преобразует в итоговый стрим.

---

Пример для `flatMap`: есть двухмерный `array` с числами, надо получить одномерный массив с числами.

Решение:

```
secondArray = Arrays.stream(array)
              .flatMapToInt(i -> Arrays.stream(i)) //преобразовываем Stream<int[]> в Stream
              .toArray(); // преобразовываем Stream в int[]
```

В этом примере создается стрим состоящий из каждого элемента первоначального массива - т.е. стрим из массивов. Потом с помощью `i -> Arrays.stream(i)` преобразовываем каждый элемент(который является массивом) стрима в стрим с числами. После этого `flatMap` собирает все получившееся стримы в один итоговый стрим.

Answer (score 2):

Выражения `map(lambda)` и `flatMap(lambda)` оба применяют анонимную функцию lambda к каждому элементу стрима.
Разница в том, что `lambda` для `map` возвращает ровно один элемент для каждого элемента стрима, а `lambda` для `flatMap` возвращает какой-то стрим (и все такие стримы склеиваются в один).

Пример из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) Java:
Если orders — стрим заказов, а каждый заказ включает в себя несколько купленных вещей (line items), то получить стрим из всех купленных вещей можно так:

```
 orders.flatMap(order -> order.getLineItems().stream())
```